# Mask input with percent sign

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I would like to allow the user to enter 1 or two numerical digits, and display the digits followed by a percent sign.  If no digits are entered, it should be blank.  The attached almost works, but doesn't show the percent sign if only one digit is entered.  Can anyone help?  Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/dm8Mb/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
<title>Mask</title> 

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script> 
$(function(){$(".percent").mask("9?9%");});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<input type="text" name="percent" class="percent" value="" />
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/dm8Mb/12/

```
$(function(){
    $(".percent").mask("9?9%");

    $(".percent").on("blur", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().length == 1 ? $(this).val() + '%' : $(this).val();
        $(this).val( value );
    })
});
```

Comment: This is very inefficient.  You're wrapping (and re-evaluating) ```$(this)``` *four* separate times, then executing the ```val()``` function three times.  You should be storing the results of these in temporary variables.  In JavaScript, variables are cheap, execution is expensive.

Comment: @MattBrock Is correct, Use the fiddle in the comments. Good answer from Zoltan.